# Excel VBA Evaluate with String in Formula

Tags: vba, excel, double-quotes

I'm trying to get VBA to evaluate a formula as it goes over a loop. The portion that fails is the Evaluate() function itself, or at least the syntax I'm using.

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Offset(All, 0) = _
     Evaluate("((SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(PercentMet!$I$2,ROW(PercentMet!$I$2:$I$27301)-ROW(PercentMet!$H$2),0)),PercentMet!$I$2:$I$27301,PercentMet!$G$2:$G$27301)/SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(PercentMet!$G$2,ROW(PercentMet!$G$2:$G$27301)-ROW(PercentMet!$G$2),0)),--(PercentMet!$I$2:$I$27301<>""NA""))))")
```

The portion that fails is the ""NA"" at the end of the formula. Using this formula each cell equates to #VALUE!

If I remove the Evaluate portion the formula works as I want, but I need Evaluate because I'm looping through various filters and each value is unique.

Entire Code is Below:

```
Sub EthFilter()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim EthName As Range, GradeName As Range, Rate As Variant, Grade As Variant
Dim One As Integer, Zero As Integer, All As Integer

Set EthName = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("J1")
Set GradeName = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K1")

One = 0
All = 0

For Each Raeth In Range("J1:J7")

Zero = 0
Rate = EthName.Offset(One, 0)

    With Worksheets("PercentMet")

        .AutoFilterMode = False

            With .Range("$A$1:$O$27301")
                .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Rate

                For Each Grades In Range("B2:B9")

                    Grade = GradeName.Offset(Zero, 0).Value

                    With Worksheets("PercentMet")

                        With .Range("$A$1:$O$27301")
                            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Grade
                            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Offset(All, 0) = _
                                Evaluate("((SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(PercentMet!$I$2,ROW(PercentMet!$I$2:$I$27301)-ROW(PercentMet!$H$2),0)),PercentMet!$I$2:$I$27301,PercentMet!$G$2:$G$27301)/SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(PercentMet!$G$2,ROW(PercentMet!$G$2:$G$27301)-ROW(PercentMet!$G$2),0)),--(PercentMet!$I$2:$I$27301<>""NA""))))")

                        End With

                    End With

                All = All + 1
                Zero = Zero + 1
                Next Grades

            End With

    End With

One = One + 1

Next Raeth

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: If I move the formula into a variable and Evaluate that I get the same output #VALUE!. If I use only the formula in excel  which counts to 291 characters I still get an output. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the length of the formula is a problem then instead of this (line breaks added for clarity):

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Offset(All, 0) = Evaluate(
"((SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(PercentMet!$I$2,ROW(PercentMet!$I$2:$I$27301)-
ROW(PercentMet!$H$2),0)),PercentMet!$I$2:$I$27301,PercentMet!$G$2:$G$27301)/
SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(PercentMet!$G$2,ROW(PercentMet!$G$2:$G$27301)-
ROW(PercentMet!$G$2),0)),--(PercentMet!$I$2:$I$27301<>""NA""))))")
```

you can use this form:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Offset(All, 0) = Worksheets("PercentMet").Evaluate(
"((SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET($I$2,ROW($I$2:$I$27301)-
ROW($H$2),0)),$I$2:$I$27301,$G$2:$G$27301)/
SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($G$2,ROW($G$2:$G$27301)-
ROW($G$2),0)),--($I$2:$I$27301<>""NA""))))")
```

Since all the inputs come from the same sheet you can use that sheet's `Evaluate` method and the formula will be evaluated in the context of that sheet.

The default `Application.Evaluate` version uses whichever sheet is Active at the time of execution.

Comment: Well I'll be darned. That fixed it.